# SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services, Subscriptions

Tags: parameters, reportingservices-2005, subscription, subscriptions

A quick one: Is it a requirement to have a parameter within the report created in Visual Studio (2005 my case), so that it runs on subscription?

I´m having problems running my subscriptions both delivered by: email and Windows file share.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running a report that accepts parameters, you either need to declare the parameter value in the subscription, or have a default parameter set in the report.

Comment: And if there is no parameter, it should run just fine?

Comment: Yes, if there are no parameters, you should not have to set anything parameter-related.  What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Found the error log, the problem was that the user running the subscription was not a AD user on the server.